# Не запускается docker контейнер mysql, помогите!

Tags: mysql, docker

Помогите знающие люди с докером. Не запускается докер контейнер mysql. В логе пишет следующее:

```
2024-01-22 13:17:22 find: '/var/lib/mysql/#innodb_temp': Permission denied
2024-01-22 13:17:22 find: '/var/lib/mysql/sys': Permission denied
2024-01-22 13:17:22 find: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql': Permission denied
2024-01-22 13:17:22 find: '/var/lib/mysql/#innodb_redo': Permission denied
2024-01-22 13:17:22 find: '/var/lib/mysql/performance_schema': Permission denied
2024-01-22 13:17:22 find: '/var/lib/mysql/#innodb_temp': Permission denied
2024-01-22 13:17:22 find: '/var/lib/mysql/sys': Permission denied
2024-01-22 13:17:22 find: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql': Permission denied
2024-01-22 13:17:22 find: '/var/lib/mysql/#innodb_redo': Permission denied
2024-01-22 13:17:22 find: '/var/lib/mysql/performance_schema': Permission denied
2024-01-22 13:17:22 chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted
2024-01-22 13:17:22 chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/client-key.pem': Operation not permitted
2024-01-22 13:17:22 chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/private_key.pem': Operation not permitted
2024-01-22 13:17:22 chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/binlog.index': Operation not permitted
2024-01-22 13:17:22 chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock': Operation not permitted
```

ну и все файлы в этом духе.
Вот compose.yaml

```
networks:
  network2:
    name: network2

services:
  nginx2:
    container_name: nginx2
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/config.d/default.conf
      - ./www:/var/www/public_html
    networks:
      - network2
    depends_on:
      - php2
      - mysql2
  php2:
    container_name: php2
    build: ./images/php
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/public_html
    networks:
      - network2
    depends_on:
      - mysql2
  mysql2:
    container_name: mysql2
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    networks:
      - network2
  phpmyadmin2:
    container_name: phpmyadmin2
    image: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 1501:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mysql2
    networks:
      - network2
    depends_on:
      - mysql2
```

Я так понял, что проблема с правами, но не понимаю какие права нужны и чему. Перепробовал всякие варианты и root ставил и mysql проблема не исчезает. Помогите разобраться плиз!!!